# basic Python if statement throw error IndentationError

Tags: python

I started to learn python on openclassroom and I can't get the if/else conditions to work.
I searched on google for several hours and I did not find a solution to my problem.

I tried to make a very simple statement like this:

```
a = 1

if a == 1:
    print("1")
else:
    print("not 1")
```

command output:

```
C:\Users\david>python
Python 3.11.2 (tags/v3.11.2:878ead1, Feb  7 2023, 16:38:35) [MSC v.1934 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> a = 1
>>>
>>> a
1
>>>
>>> if a == 1:
... print("a equal 1")
  File "<stdin>", line 2
    print("a equal 1")
    ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block after 'if' statement on line 1
>>>
```

i tried the same exact code in pycharm and it is working. but it doesn't work in cmd for some reason

Comment: You're **not** indenting it in the REPL. `...    print("a equal 1")`.

Comment: Look at the difference between your code up top and your code in the "command output" section. You put spaces in where they're needed up top, but left them out when typing at the REPL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because you aren't indenting property in cmd.

```py
>>> a = 1
>>> if a == 1:
...     print("a == 1")
a == 1
```

To indent in cmd, simply press `tab`, and it will indent.

Comment: Questions caused by typographic errors should be closed, not answered. See the _Answer Well-Asked Questions_ section of [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 0):

You may receive an "IndentationError" in Python when your code is not indented correctly. In your case, however, you do not have an indented block after your if statement on line 1.

Comment: Questions caused by  typographic errors should be closed, not answered. See the _Answer Well-Asked Questions_ section of [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)